# Why only the lowest available file descriptor is allocated in UNIX?

Tags: c, linux, unix

In a group talk I was intrigued by this question -

**Why UNIX standard demands the guarantee of allocation of only lowest available file descriptor for a process ?**

And only possible answer that I could thought of was **scalability**. Since we always choose the least available descriptor, the **used** portion of the descriptor bitmap is mostly dense and thus the growth of array is slower.

I was just wondering if there are any other reasons which I am not aware of.

Also, do we have some scenarios where logical conclusions (those we can use in a program) can be made if we know that a given descriptor is bigger/smaller than the other. My understanding though does NOT allows using such technique because it does NOT guarantee the **age** of the descriptor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are various reasons, but the ultimate one is "because that's the way it has always been done".

1. It is easy to track through the list of file descriptors to find the first unused one.
2. It is determinate.  This was important before the `dup2()` call was available.

Classically, the file descriptor table for a process was a fixed size, and quite small (20 in 7th Edition Unix, IIRC).

The deterministic mechanism was crucial for I/O redirection in shell.  For example:

```
cat file1 file2 > file3
```

The shell needed to redirect standard output to `file3`.  Therefore, it could use:

```
close(1);  // Standard output
if (open("file3", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT, 0666) != 1)
   …error creating file…
```

and it would know that because standard input was already open (file descriptor 0), the `open()` would return file descriptor 1.

These days, you can't deduce anything much from a file descriptor value.  I can write:

```
int fd1 = open(filename, flags, mode);
int fd2 = dup2(fd1, 1024);
close(fd1);
```

and the fact that `fd2` (should) contain 1024 doesn't tell you anything about the order in which it was opened compared to file descriptor 3 (which might plausibly be returned by the next `open()` call).

Comment: Thanks. I used to think that "first unused" can be found faster if we use round robin allocation.

Comment: Yes, but you lose the determinacy, and determinacy is more important than speed, especially when the table is only 20 file descriptors long (and I think the limit may have been lower still in older versions of Unix than 7th Edition).

Answer (score 2):

If you close standard input (fd 0) and then open a new file, it will get fd 0. (Similarly for fds 1 and 2, `stdout` and `stderr`, if the lower fds have not been closed.) That predictability is useful and was used in many unix programs before `dup2` was standardized in order to redirect standard input/output/error in a child process.

Comment: Thanks. So that's where my question starts. How do we use that predictability in program? Please elaborate on this.

Comment: As @johnathanleffler points out, these days you would use `dup2`. But the traditional way was to fork, close stdin, open what you want the redirected stdin to be (or /dev/null for a daemon), repeat for stdout and stderr, and finally exec.

Answer (score 0):

Simple: In 1970, 64 **KB** (65536 **bytes**) were **a lot**. That's the kind of system on which Unix was invented (a [PDP-7](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDP-7) to be exact which came with 9 **KB** by default with an option to upgrade it to 144 KB ... for, say, $20'000).

In that kind of environment, every single bit is valuable (which explains some of the weird stuff that confuse the spoiled brats today like using integers to save pointers and vice versa).

So the algorithm would try to allocate the first free file descriptor in a very small table (which was fixed in size at the time). This would also make the algorithm terminate faster which was also good since most computers could only execute a few 10-100 thousand commands per second.